# Laravel(php) + разное описание для пользователей с ролью

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Может кто-то подсказать как реализовать разные поля для разных ролей. К примеру у пользователей в профиле есть номер телефона, а у администратора отдел и организация. Что-то на подобии? Или ссылочку, где можно почиатть [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Админ от пользователя отличается только ролями. А из этого следует, что админ и пользователь - это одна таблица со всеми необходимыми полями. Просто для определённых ролей некоторые поля не нужно показывать. А у вас аж 3 таблицы ...

Answer (score 3):

2 крайние таблицы - это вообще какой-то прикол... Сущности не должны быть таблицами.

У Вас есть таблица `users`, таблица `roles`.
Добавляете таблицу `user_has_roles` (назначение ролей), если ролей может быть много на одного пользователя. Если нет, то просто поле в `users` — "role_id".

В `users` добавляете поля ("department", "organization", "phone"), которые содержат информацию для конкретного пользователя. Можно нормализовать таблицу: создать таблицы `user_fields` ("id", "name", "title"), `user_has_fields` ("user_id", "user_field_id", "value") и в них писать информацию в зависимости от заполнения в профиле. Так не будет лишних пустот в таблице с пользователями. Но работать становится сложнее.

Дальше уже в своей бизнес-логике обрабатываете, что может заполнять админ, а что пользователь, и, соответственно, в шаблоне тоже выводите в зависимости от роли пользователя телефон или отдел с организацией. Именно кодом это делается. База данных только хранит данные.

Можете в принципе не городить велосипеды с системой прав и воспользоваться пакетом [Spatie Laravel Permissions](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/introduction)

---

UPD. В целом, Вы можете завести 2 таблицы `user_contacts` ("user_id", "phone"), `user_organizations` ("user_id", "department", "organization"). НО они в любом случае не зависят от ролей в БД. Должна браться связь с моделью в зависимости от существования у пользователя роли.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я знаю этот пакет. Но в данной ситуации я думаю как реализовать регистрацию, с разными полями в БД для пользователей. Ну например: Преподаватель> (Поля) -> Квалификация, Направление. А у студента -> кафедра, группа. По сути это вообще разные поля, хранить в одной таблице по идее не правильно("user_fields"). А если нужна валидация? Записывать в пустые поля null? А если на фронте выводить для одной роли - одни поля а, для другой - вторые, скрывать пустые тоже не правильно по идее. Мне бы понять как при авторизации - у каждой роли свой профиль (без пустых и скрытых полей)

Comment: зашел как студент одна информация в профиле, под преподавателем - другая. (P.S. Мне не нужнен готовый ответ, но что-бы почитать/познать по этому поводу было-бы шикарно)

Comment: Я сделал бы всё-же на spatie/laravel-permission, но к таблице users прикрепил бы полиморфное отношение один к одному - teacher_profiles, student_profiles etc. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations